# pull row with max date from groupby in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to pull the max date from a df in the below format

```
columns: index1 index2 col1

place1

      | 2018 | 5 | 
      | 2019 | 4 |
      | 2020 | 2 |

place2

      | 2016 | 9 |
      | 2017 | 8 |

place3

      | 2018 | 6 |
      | 2019 | 1 |
```

I'm trying to pull rows out for the maximum years available for each place. In the above example the final df would be:

```
place1 | 2020 | 2
place2 | 2017 | 8
place3 | 2019 | 1
```

Comment: `df.sort_values("index2").groupby("index1").last()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataframe.sort_values().groupby().last()`
To find the maximum value in a `group`

In your case you have to do

```
df.sort_values("index2").groupby("index1").last()
```

I think it may work for you

Comment: The OP wants to get `max` in each group.

Comment: Opps! Sorry I have not seen it

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I receive a KeyError: 'index2' when running. index2 is already sorted, but output when removing sort_values is identical to initial question output

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie in python but might be it can help:

```
import pandas as pd
data=[['place1','2018','5'],
     ['place1','2019','4'],
     ['place1','2020','2'],
     ['place2','2016','9'],
     ['place2','2017','8'],
     ['place3','2018','6'],
     ['place3','2019','1']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['index1','index2','col1'])
df.set_index(['index1','index2'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True) 
df=df.sort_values(['index1','index2'],ascending=False).groupby('index1').first()
df.set_index('index2',append=True,inplace=True)
```